# Tasker - overlay not working

Tags: tasker, touchscreen

I own a rooted Xiaomi Redmi Note 3 smartphone and  experience phantom touches in a horizontal rectangular zone on my touchscreen.

To fix this, I am trying to create a transparent blocking overlay scene via tasker, but am unable to do it. I can create dialog and activity scenes and they display properly if I create an action to show the scene.

However, if I try to make any overlay scene, nothing happens at all when I click the play button to display the scene. I do see a green dot, but nothing happens even after clicking the play button repeatedly. Could someone help me with this or suggest me another method to block touch input from specific region?

If I click play after the green dot appears, I get a red dot with this message-

```
23.30.36/TD data: haveStatic: Passive true
23.30.36/TD getStatic: Passive load true
23.30.36/TD getStatic: Passive load: true
23.30.36/E doShowScene: scene already visible: Nzj
```

As an example, even if I take this simple scene, overlay doesn't work.

```
Scene: Nzj
P:1062x168  L:1062x168 

    Orientation: User
    Background Colour: #AE480505
    Action Bar Style: System
    Title: Nzj
    Subtitle: 
    Icon: null
    Tab Labels:
```

Edit: It's working now. Just add to give tasker the permission to open popup windows. I don't know why it did not request for the permission itself.

Comment: Can you export your Overlay Scene and link it here? Which part of the screen are you trying to block from touch input?

Comment: I am trying to block touch input from a 0.5cm wide rectangular strip above the centre of my phone. I have edited the question. Is this the information that you want?

Comment: Can you import this project and see if it works or not? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3e5b17a6efc3865d8f586e2147ff594f // It works in my device, though it is not fully transparent.

Comment: It says that phantom isn't defined if I try to import it. Also, I have edited the question.